# Kernel Panic at boot Xubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel, xubuntu

I'm receiving a kernel panic when I try to boot Xubuntu 14.04.2 - this is my System:

- Windows 8 (sda2)
- Xubuntu 14.04.2 (sda7)
- Kali Linux (sda9)

First, I installed Xubuntu next Windows. That was no problem. Kali didn't install the bootloader, so I had to install GRUB manually from USB. It worked .... but today, after a update from Xubuntu, I'm receiving following message every start:

[image]

I'm really afraid I don't know what to do. I've tried some found stuff in Google, but I doesn't work. So, what do I have to do?

PS: Windows and Kali are booting without problems.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you manually installed kernel 3.19.0-15 to Xubuntu.

Xubuntu 14.04.2 is shipped with 3.13 kernels, not like Ubuntu 14.04.2 as far as I know.

Ubuntu kernel 3.19.0-15 has never been published in Ubuntu repositories and has issues.

So you need to boot with some stable kernel using grub menu and remove this kernel image.

If you need 3.19 so much you can run

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

This will install stable 3.19.0-18 supported kernel.

If a non-LTS version of Xubuntu is installed then run

```
sudo apt-get update $$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

to get a supported kernel.

Comment: Hi. I didn't change anything ... It worked before  .

Comment: But btw what can I do so far?

Comment: You may added some repository or something. It does not really matter how this happened: intentionally or not. Just try the given solution. Or is it Xubuntu 15.04?

Comment: Thats possible (15.10) How to install this package? In a live system?

Comment: 15.10 is not released yet. It is at an early stage of development. And it is not supported. Try to recall the version. But anyway you need to boot with another kernel. My command won't work for 15.04 or 15.10.

Comment: You mean reinstall?

Comment: Booting with 3.16 kernel is also not worling. But anyway i will reinstall ir

Comment: If it is really 15.10, then crashing is OK at this stage.

Comment: And when not? What shall I do then?

Comment: Do not install development versions not for testing or development purposes. Install stable releases.

Comment: Just checked it. Its 14.04.2